# Mysql inserts empty rows

Tags: php, mysql, sql, ajax

I have an array of object that I want to insert into database.
So I'm looping all objects with for loop.

I'm sending `$offer` and `$gameid` with ajax
`$offer` is array with 10 items and `$gameid` is just `integer`

All variables have data because it `echo` them.

I'm working on xampp with localhost

```
include "../../inc/connect.php";

$offer = @$_POST['offer'];
$gameid = @$_POST['gameid'];

$query = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO items VALUES (id, gameid, assetid, name, icon, price, owner)");

for($i = 0; $i < count($offer) - 1; $i++) {
    $assetid = $offer[$i]['assetid'];
    $name = $offer[$i]['name'];
    $icon = $offer[$i]['icon'];
    $price = $offer[$i]['price'];

    $query_array = array('id' => '', 'gameid' => $gameid, 'assetid' => $assetid, 'name' => $name, 'icon' => $icon, 'price' => $price, 'owner' => $steamid);

    $query->execute($query_array);

echo "
<div class='item'>
    <div class='left'>
        <img src='$avatar' />
        <div class='names'>
            <p>$username</p>
            <p>$name</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class='right'>
        <div class='price'>
            $" . $price . "
        </div>
        <div class='item-icon'>
            <img src='http://cdn.steamcommunity.com/economy/image/$icon' />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>  
";
}
```

Connect

```
$user = "root";
$pass = "";

$db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=website', $user, $pass);
```

Table

[image]

What I get when `$query->execute($query_array)`

[image]

No errors in `mysql_error.log` or in ajax data

Comment: First : I hope you're not using sql root user as production site :(

Comment: Don't worry I change it when I upload my site in the server

Comment: `VALUES (id, gameid, assetid, name, icon, price, owner)` - that's faling you here; *think* string literal. and where's the "ajax" for this?

Comment: You need colons before your placeholders. `VALUES (:id, :gameid, :assetid, :name, :icon, :price, :owner)`. Otherwise it's treating them as column names.

Comment: Thank you. Post an answer and I accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need colons on your placeholders, or else it will treat the values as column names:

```
$query = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO items VALUES (:id, :gameid, :assetid, :name, :icon, :price, :owner)");

$query_array = array(':id' => '', ':gameid' => $gameid, ':assetid' => $assetid, ':name' => $name, ':icon' => $icon, ':price' => $price, ':owner' => $steamid);
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with your query. It should be like this:

```
$query = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO items 
    (id, gameid, assetid, name, icon, price, owner) 
    VALUES (:id, :gameid, :assetid, :name, :icon, :price, :owner)"
);
```